# QValidator in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am validating my TextBox to take only numbers between 1-75.
I am able to do this by using below code :

```
QValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(1, 75, this);
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
edit->setValidator(validator);
```

But now the problem is it takes zero also. I want to avoid Zero 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write your validator like that:

```
 class lvalidator : public QValidator
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit lvalidator(QObject *parent = 0);
        virtual State validate ( QString & input, int & pos ) const
        {
            if (input.isEmpty())
                return Acceptable;

            bool b;
            int val = input.toInt(&b);

            if ((b == true) && (val > 0) && (val < 76))
            {
                return Acceptable;
            }
            return Invalid;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is there a reason you allocated heap memory for the bool rather than using the stack and taking the address of it? Does this not create a memory leak?

Comment: Do not forget to define the constructor :)

Answer (score 12):

You are not currently validating: when you set a `QValidator` you are just filtering characters to those which could compose a valid input.

In order to do the actual validation, you have to check that [`QLineEdit::hasAcceptableInput()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#acceptableInput-prop) returns `true`.

For example, in a slot connected to the `textChanged()` signal, you could, depending on the value of the `acceptableInput` property, enable/disable the button submitting the data, preventing the user to go further with an invalid value, and/or change the text color (red for invalid).

For numerical values, you can also use a `QSpinBox` instead of `QLineEdit`. You can define its range (min/max), and its behavior if the value is not valid when the editing finishes (with [`QSpinBox::setCorrectionMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#correctionMode-prop)).

Answer (score 2):

When you write '0' Qt interprets than  a plausible intermediate value during editing.
If you don't like this behavior, you need create an inheritance class from `QIntValidator` and re-implement the following function:

```
virtual QValidator::State validate ( QString & input, int & pos ) const
```

Regards.